# Include new tables with data to existing Debezium connector not working

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Below is my MySQL debezium connector. I have created my connector with 2 tables. Later, when I added the third table in the same connector configuration, it didn't work.

Connector got created successfully, But the third table doesnt have any kafka messages. Its empty

Any changes to be done in the below config

```
{
    "name": "xxx",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
      "tasks.max": "1",  
      "database.hostname": "xxx.rds.amazonaws.com",
      "database.port": "3306",
      "database.user": "REDACTED",
      "database.password": "REDACTED",
      "database.server.id": "54006",
      "database.server.name": "abc",
      "database.whitelist": "abc",
      "table.whitelist": "abc.t1,abc.t2,abc.t3",
      "database.history.consumer.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
      "database.history.producer.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
      "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-512",
      "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-512",
      "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"REDACTED\" password=\"REDACTED\";",
      "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config":"org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"REDACTED\" password=\"REDACTED\";",
      "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "b-1,b-2,b-3",  
      "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.abc",
      "debezium.snapshot.new.tables": "parallel",
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
      "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
      "snapshot.mode": "when_needed",
      "snapshot.locking.mode": "none",
      "include.schema.changes": true,
      "min.row.count.to.stream.results": 100000,
      "snapshot.fetch.size": 50000,
      "max.queue.size": 81290,
      "max.batch.size": 20480
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because other tables are busy being read? `"tasks.max": "1"`... You should first try to copy the config and make a separate one for the new table rather than edit the running connector

Comment: @OneCricketeer  Got this response for another question site..  Changes to the whitelist/blacklist config are not yet supported at this point. This is currently being worked on (see DBZ-175), and we hope to have preview support for this in one of the next releases. There's a pending PR for this, which needs a bit more work, though. Do you have any idea whether its supported now ( Adding tables to whitelist ) ?

Comment: I don't use Debezium. Did you find that JIRA ticket?